# How to avoid audio loop lag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to get a sound looped on html 5. The sound.loop = true; works, but when the sound get finished, there's a silence between looping. How can I avoid that? Thanks a lot, here's the code:

```
<audio id="ruido">
<source src="ruido.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="ruido.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<script>
   var sound = document.getElementById("ruido");
   sound.loop = true;
   sound.play();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a JavaScript function to loop when an 'ended' event is called.

```
<audio id="loopMe" controls preload>
  <source src="ruido.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="ruido.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

document.getElementById('loopMe').addEventListener('ended', function(){
this.currentTime = 0;
this.play();
}, false);
```

Or better yet try the [SeamlessLoop](https://github.com/Hivenfour/SeamlessLoop) library, Reproduce seamless/gapless audio loops on HTML5/JavaScript without specific browser Audio APIs.

Comment: I tried to use SeamlessLoop library, seems great, but don't know how the hell to know the URI of my audio files. Guess I'll took Seamless as a reference for coding. As far as I saw, every navigator have their own lag on loops.